# Different hash values for notepad.exe

Tags: c#, .net, sha256

I am trying to calculate the SHA256 hash of notepad.exe.

The following was the code utilized for the same,

```
public string GetSHA256Hash(string path)
{
    string hashdata = null;
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        SHA256CryptoServiceProvider hashprovider = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        hashdata = BitConverter.ToString(hashprovider.ComputeHash(fs)).Replace("-", string.Empty);       
    }

    return hashdata;        
}
```

However when I counter-check it with powershell `Get-FileHash` i get a different value.

I have checked it with the debugger and the file path going into the `path` parameter is correct.

Is there anything wrong with the above code.

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you try it on non windows files. I'd guess this might be a windows virtualization issue. If I try running powershell's Get-FileHash against windows\system32\notepad.exe I get different values depending on whether I run Powershell (x86) or Powershell.

Comment: @sgmore, You were right. The hash generated with Powershell (x86) did match up with the code in the question.

Comment: @sgmore Would you mind elaborating on how virtualization could affect the hashes generated ?

Comment: The OS has two mirrors of the system files: 32-bit and 64-bit. What file it opens depends on which shims are in play (based on whether your process is 32-bit or 64-bit). The files have different contents.